# java - using joda time to get milliseconds value depending on time unit and ammount

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime, epoch

I have a String representing unit of time ("days"/"hours"/"minutes") and a value representing the amount , so, for example, I have **6** and "**days**", which means 6 days ago (time unit and amount can vary, and together they mean `some time ago`).

What I want, using `joda time`, is to give a int value to each one of those combinations representing the epoch of that time (so, for example, get the epoch of **6 days ago**, or **5 minutes ago**).

How can I achieve that? I do have a map that looks like this:

```
private Map<String, DurationFieldType> durationFieldTypeMap = new HashMap<String, DurationFieldType>() {{
        put("minutes", DurationFieldType.minutes());
        put("hours", DurationFieldType.hours());
        put("days", DurationFieldType.days());
    }};
```

Is that the way to do? how can I calculate the epoch based on the time unit and amount?

Comment: Why just not using a simple POJO class for this?

Comment: This question is quite broad as it stands. Also, what do you mean by 'epoch'? 'Is that the way to do it?'  - well what you have written is a start. Convert the strings to durations.Then just use `DateTime.now().minus(parsedDuration).toInstant();`